# Use one object value as a key to access other object value in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, handlebars.js

I have 2 different objects:

1) In global.json

```
var objA = {
    "menu": {
        "icon": [
            {
                "network": "mail",
            },
            {
                "network": "facebook",
            },
            {
                "network": "twitter",
            },
            {
                "network": "googleplus",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2) In index.json

```
var objB = {
    "facebook": {
        "data": "Facebook Data",
    },
    "twitter": {
        "data": "Twitter Data",
    },
    "mail": {
        "data": "Mail Data",
    },
    "googleplus": {
        "data": "GooglePlus Data",
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the second object value by using first object value as a key in **.hbs** file, just like we do in javascript.

*Like for example:* If I want to access twitter data, I will use the following code in javascript to access that.

```
for(var i=0; i<objA["menu"]["icon"].length; i++){
    console.log(objB[objA["menu"]["icon"][i]["network"]]["data"]);
}
```

I am running a each loop in a **.hbs** file:

```
{{#each global.objA.menu.icon}}
    <li>{{data}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Here I want to show each social *data* based on the *network*.

Answer (score 0):

I have zero knowledge about handlebars, but assuming it is at least a  javascript,

```
data = objA.menu.icon.map(e=>objB[e.network])
```

should fulfill your last object desire.

```js
var objA = {
    "menu": {
        "icon": [
            {
                "network": "mail",
            },
            {
                "network": "facebook",
            },
            {
                "network": "twitter",
            },
            {
                "network": "googleplus",
            }
        ]
    }
};

var objB = {
    "facebook": {
        "data": "Facebook Data",
    },
    "twitter": {
        "data": "Twitter Data",
    },
    "mail": {
        "data": "Mail Data",
    },
    "googleplus": {
        "data": "GooglePlus Data",
    }
};

data = objA.menu.icon.map(e=>objB[e.network])

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @marmeladze for your help, time and your try, but it is not a javascript.
The answer you gave will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a combination of the [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) and [with](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#with) built-in helpers. `lookup` acts as a way to use variable keys and `with` sets a context to allow you to access each network object's properties.

```js
{{#each global.objA.menu.icon}}
  {{#with (lookup @root/global/objB this.network)}}
    {{data}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
// outputs (no formatting)
// 'Mail DataFacebook DataTwitter DataGooglePlus Data'
```